# Why is there no B-field parallel force on an electron orbiting a magnetic field line?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, electrons, magnetic-moment

If an orbiting electron creates a toroidal magnetic field like a ring of current does, and this field is oriented opposite to the magnetic field line the electron is orbiting, then why is the electron not repelled by the applied field that it orbits (driven along the field line) like 2 end to end bar magnets of opposite polarity?

Comment: @AaronStevens That's true, but that's not the reason for the phenomenon the question is asking about.  You could have a uniformly charged ring rotating in a constant normal magnetic field (making the problem magnetostatic), and the question would be the same.

Comment: electrons are quantum mechanical entities, and interact with macroscopic magnetic fields as single charge particles. If you are thinking of orbitals in atoms, then there exist corrections due to magnetic field interactions  http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/hydfin.html

Comment: @Buzz Then I guess it depends on if the externally applied field is uniform or not.

Comment: @annav A moving point charge will generate a magnetic field.  It is more complicated than the field of a steady current.  However, the qualitative problem the question is asking about still exists when there is just the field of a single charge in circular motion.

Comment: @Matthew Is the externally applied field uniform?

Comment: @Buzz  think that the derived interaction between a charged particle and a constant B already takes care of that,  when one derives F=Bqv which defines a circle if the motion is perpendicular to the field, that is how the moving charge interacts with the magnetic field at delta(t). A ring of charges/(a current) would define a collective field that would interact as an electromagnet (two magnets)?

Comment: @AaronStevens Let's say we're inside a solenoid and the field is uniform

Comment: @annav If a ring of current (with current direction opposite that of the solenoid) was placed inside the solenoid, would it be forced along the field lines via magnetic repulsion?

Comment: A torque appears that tends to orient magnetic fields in the same direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the applied magnetic field is uniform then there cannot be a net force on the current loop. This is because the magnetic force $\text d\mathbf F$ experienced by a small part of the loop of length $\text dl$ of current $I$ is given by
$$\text d\mathbf F=I\text d\mathbf l\times\mathbf B$$

If we integrate this around the loop for a uniform field you will find that the net force is $0$ (and the loop will be either under stretching or compressive forces). So for the example given in the comments, a ring of current inside a solenoid would not experience a net force in the direction of the solenoid (it could experience a torque though)

However if the field is not uniform, then the net force will be non-zero in some direction. This is because around the loop the cross products will have non-zero components in the same direction. It is in this direction that the net force will be in. See the picture below

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm still trying to understand how the current loop is different from a bar magnet. In the figure above, could we not pretend that the current loop is a bar magnet with north pole on the right? And wouldn't that cause repulsion due to antiparallel field lines?

Comment: @Matthew Are you referring to the left or right figure? Also keep in mind that the current direction on those figures represent positive charge motion. You can most certainly think of the current loop as a sort of bar magnet. In both figures the North Pole would be to the left. Just use your right hand rule.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say north pole on the left, which would apply to both figures since current direction is the same. But if it was a bar magnet in both figures with north pole on the left, I guess the net forces would be the same, so maybe I made an incorrect assumption. Would a bar magnet oriented along field lines feel any force in a uniform magnetic field?

Comment: @Matthew No. A bar magnet in a uniform magnetic field would not experience a net force.

Comment: I apologize. I was assuming that antiparallel magnetic field lines repel each other face-on in the along-line direction, so thank you for correcting me. Your image has helped me to understand that the repulsion is in the cross-line direction, which I guess is a purely magnetic way to think about things like Z-pinch between wires.